# Ubuntu Live CD and Slow Wifi

Tags: networking, live-usb

I've experienced a strange issue with Ubuntu 16.10 today.

Trying to installing Ubuntu today, I created a live usb. Boot on it.

Then, I've tried basic stuff to check if ubuntu was compatible with my laptop hardware. Especially the wifi card (ath10k).

It was, I've tried:

- some connection tests: OK
- some speed tests (wget -O /dev/null some_url): ~1500KB/s

So, all seem to be good, I install it.
Here come some weird situation. After the fresh installation and the boot on HDD, I launched a:
`sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

And WOW ! That's slow (~50KB/s).

So I try to run an another speed test with `wget` and the problem is confirmed. The connexion is drastically slowed down.

I'm the only one on the connexion.
So far, that's what I've tried to resolve the problem:

- Enabling the 11n_disable bit
- Turning off the power saving on wifi

Didn't solve the problem.

But I can't figured out what it's the real difference between LiveUSB and fresh installed HDD version.

If anyone encounter this problem before or have any clue of where it can come from. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Normally the update process will be slow from Ubuntu server. We have 100 Mbps leased line, Here also the same. I suspect the issue is not with your data line

Comment: Yep, that's why I had tried the same command in both cases: `wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip`. The differences between Windows && liveUSB and the HDD booting Linux is really significant.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu with connection on, i mean Ubuntu installed updates while installation process? It could be a kernel regression.  Check for installed kernels `ls /boot/vmlinuz-*` and the one running `uname -a` then reboot, press shift to get grub menu, select advanced menu then older kernel.